# Query if a customer ID has a previous order in the last week: How To?

Tags: sqlite, date

I am using SQLite 3.7.4 and have a table that includes:

```
TABLE: 'Orders'
ID     OrderDate
1234   2011-06-01 00:00:00
1245   2011-06-04 00:00:00
1234   2011-06-05 00:00:00
```

I'd like to be able to select the 'OrderDate' & 'ID' where, for a given OrderDate there is a previous order in the last 1 week.

So, for the data above:

- The first record ID 1234 has an order
  on 2011-06-01 00:00:00, but has none
  previous - so isn't selected.
- The next record ID 1245 has an order
  on 2011-06-04 00:00:00 but none in
  week prior to 2011-06-04, so not
  selected.
- The 3rd record ID 1234 order made on
  2011-06-05 00:00:00 has a previous
  order on 2011-06-01, so this record
  is selected.

I have just about managed to get my head around using `strftime('%s',OrderDate)` for date differences,but can't work out how to query by taking the `yyyy-mm-dd` part of the OrderDate record and looking back '-7 days' to see if there are 1 or more records within that range ?

Any guideance appreciated :)

Comment: Just a quick suggestion - from your explanation I gather that `ID` refers to a customer, client or some other entity, not an Order. If you have an `ID` column on your Orders table, it *should* be an Order Id. You could use CustomerID or whatever else to differentiate (and should probably include both, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Not certain I understand, but this gives the output you're looking for, given the sample data.

```
sqlite> select o1.id, o1.orderdate from orders o1
   ...> inner join orders o2 on (o1.id = o2.id
   ...> and o2.orderdate >= date(o1.orderdate, '-7 day')
   ...> and o2.orderdate < o1.orderdate);
1234|2011-06-05
```

You should probably look at SQLite [Date and Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Since the entries have hours, minutes and seconds set to 00, I would suspect that also a record with the same day is acceptable. Hence: `inner join ... on o1.rowid <> o2.rowid and o1.id = o2.id and o2.orderdate BETWEEN ... AND ...)`

Comment: @Benoit: You might be right. I've never seen an accounting system that recorded the time of order, though, and all the time components are zeroes. (Not that *that* observation means much. Maybe the OP will comment.)

Comment: Many thanks. I left the HH:mm:ss zero'd - but the actual data has this populated also. The Query gives me a list - i will validate it but it looks right. Excellent. Many thanks :)